# Issue while building openjdk riscv on local

Tags: java, build, open-source, riscv

I have created **riscv chroot**. Inside chroot, I am trying to **build openjdk riscv** from the source code.
I cloned the source code from https://github.com/openjdk/riscv-port.git. I have successfully executed **bash configure** as it is the first step in README.
While executing the second step, **make images**, I am getting the following error.

**Error Log -**

root@ryze:/openjdk/riscv-port# make images
Building target 'images' in configuration 'linux-riscv64-server-release'
/usr/bin/bash: line 2: /dev/fd/63: No such file or directory

ERROR: Build failed for target 'images' in configuration 'linux-riscv64-server-release' (exit code 1)

No indication of failed target found.
HELP: Try searching the build log for '] Error'.
HELP: Run 'make doctor' to diagnose build problems.

make[1]: *** [/openjdk/riscv-port/make/Init.gmk:320: main] Error 1
make: *** [/openjdk/riscv-port/make/Init.gmk:186: images] Error 2

**Please note that I am building openjdk inside chroot.**

I tried to find some solution on internet, but failed to find any.

Comment: Are you sure it supports building in a chroot? Why is that a requirement?

Comment: If you are going to build this way, it looks like you will need to bind mount "/dev/" into the chrooted namespace.

Comment: But read through the OpenJDK build instructions.  They explain how to set up the chroot (with Debian sysroots).  They also include specific build instructions for RISCV ("Building for RISC-V") which don't seem to involve a chroot at all.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Yes, because I want to build openjdk for riscv. So I created a riscv RFS(root filesystem) using mmdebstrap and taking chroot inside RFS and building openjdk.

Comment: @StephenC I also tried after bind mounting dev, but it is still throwing the same error.

Comment: @StephenC I tried to setup with Debian sysroots, it is still not working. I am getting following error while running "bash configure".

checking how to run the C preprocessor... /lib/cpp
configure: error: in `/media/varun/scratch2/ajay_java/TRY/cross_compile/riscv-port':
configure: error: C preprocessor "/lib/cpp" fails sanity check